# Is using Any for Union type a good idea?

Tags: scala

I want to create a class generator (for Avro models). I have a problem because sometime the field of the class I generate could be one of many different types, let's say it could be an `Int` or a `String` or whatever. The simple idea is to create that field with the type `Any` and check at runtime that it is ok.

The problem is that using `Any` discard some of the powerfull features of the scala type system. Some bug in the code will not be caught at compile time (if I give a `List` to a function expecting a `String` or `Int` covered by an `Any`).

For example :

Let's I have this description of my class :

```
{"className" : "MyClass", "fields" : [
  { "fieldName" : "myField", "type" : ["String", "Int"]}
]}
```

From this description, I create this class :

```
class MyClass(myField: Any)
```

I want to create something like this :

```
class MyClass(myField: String or Int)
```

Should I stop using `Any` ? Is using `Any` generally considered a good idea in the scala community ?

Comment: What not create a polymorphic class? `class Foo[T]`

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a clue how many different types can a field take or if the different types share a common trait.

Comment: Using `Any` is rarely a good idea. Hard to give advise without more context, though.

Comment: can you give more details about how you plan to use the field that you're currently setting as Any? from what you're describing so far, it sounds like @YuvalItzchakov 's suggestion is what you should do.

Comment: *"The problem is that I don't have a clue how many different types can a field take or if the different types share a common trait."* That's ok. Polymorphic classes operate on `T`, which if you don't constraint, can be used for anything. As long as the classes operations in regards to `T` are general and not specific, i.e relay on it being an `Int` or `String`, you should be ok.

Comment: *"The problem is that I don't have a clue how many different types can a field take or if the different types share a common trait."* A better alternative to using `Any` often consists in defining an appropriate algebraic data type. Surely, you could create an ADT that would cover all the possible Avro schemas.

Comment: @I think this is the right answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is using Any generally considered a good idea in the scala community?

Nope. `Any` means no type information, so it's generally considered a bad practice.

In Scala you can express a union type using `Either`, although it gets cumbersome if you have a lot of possible types in the union. Example:

```
class MyClass(myField: Either[String, Int]) {
  def doSomething = myField match {
    case Left(myStringField) => ???
    case Right(myIntField) => ???
  }
}
```

Another viable approach would be to make `MyClass` generic in its type:

```
class MyClass[A](myField: A)
```

However this is not setting any constraint on the type of `A`.

In order to place a constraint, e.g. make it a finite subset of types, you can use ad-hoc polymorphism:

```
trait MyConstraint[A]
class MyClass[A: MyConstraint](myField: A)
```

Now `new MyClass(myValue)` won't compile unless there is an implicit `MyConstraint[A]` in scope. Now you can whitelist the types you want to allow using implicit values

```
implicit object IntConstraint extends MyConstraint[Int]
implicit object StringConstraint extends MyConstraint[String]
```

Example:

```
new MyClass(42) // ok, there's implicit evidence of MyConstraint[Int]
new MyClass("foo") // ok, there's implicit evidence of MyConstraint[String]
new MyClass(false) // won't compile, no implicit evidence of MyConstraint[Boolean]
```

In technical terms, `MyConstraint` is a type class, used to refine the type `A` in the constructor of `MyClass`.

You can characterize a type class even further, by requiring that a set of operations are defined for each of its instances. E.g.

```
trait MyConstraint[A] {
  def mandatoryOp: A
}

implicit object IntConstraint extends MyConstraint[Int] {
  def mandatoryOp = 42
}

implicit object StringConstraint extends MyConstraint[String] {
  def mandatoryOp = "foo"
}

class MyClass[A](myField: A)(implicit ev: MyConstraint[A]) {
  def doSomething: A = ev.mandatoryOp 
}
```

Please note that `A: MyConstraint` is just syntactic sugar for requiring an implicit parameter of type `MyConstraint[A]`. In the last example I chose the explicit syntax in order to have the implicit parameter `ev` available in scope.

Comment: Why no mention of the ADT pattern? It seems like the most appropriate approach, here.